# SublimeText3: Error trying to parse settings for c++ setup

Tags: c++, autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I was trying to add the  auto complete feature to sublime for all brackets , inverted commas etc. and escape it using tab but getting parsing error using the following code

```
    // Auto-complete behaviour for ), ], '', ""
    // Bind to ,  to step over the auto-completed character(s)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  { "keys": ["enter"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
      [
          { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\\]'\"]", "match_all": true },
          { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "[(['\"]", "match_all": true },
          { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
      ]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
      [
          { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)\\]'\"]", "match_all": true },
          { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "[(['\"]", "match_all": true },
          { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
      ]
  }
```

but after that i am getting this as result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you install package dev for Sublime Text 3 it'll also show you where your errors are with a coloured cursor.
The error is at line 10, character 3, so some line numbers would help with the code you've posted..

I've pasted it into my keymap file (in ST3) and can detect no errors with the code you've posted, is that the entire contents of .sublime-keymap ?
I can also recommend posting your question on the [Sublime Text Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/) they may be able to help you too.

You could be missing a comma after your final curly bracket, if there's more keybindings in that file i.e. the last line should be:-

## },

Comment: thanks for the help it worked, I just figured out that there are previous changes that i've done and that doesn't have comma in the end as you suggested